# How can I change Tooltips delay?

Tags: interface

I'm using [Bforartists](https://www.bforartists.de/) for the less intensive keyboard usage, and while I like the tiny icons quite often I want to know what they are for, but right now it feels like it takes too long for the tooltips to show up and I would like to shorten the delay and can't find a way to do it.

**Anyway to change the tooltips delay?**

Comment: [Sorry for this.](https://imgur.com/a/hTPBT4f)

Comment: I think question like this should be asked on this Blender's fork support site